# Passing Longitude and Latitude from JSON to Map Control

Tags: json, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Hi I am trying to create an app to help people learn a new area and find shops and such like, this means displaying a different map for each item. I have included the long and lat in the json file:

```
[
  {
    "UniqueId": "Group-1-Item-1",
    "Title": "Bear Grill",
    "Subtitle": "Grill",
    "ImagePath": "Assets/theBearGrill.png",
    "Description" : "Item Description:",
    "Content" : "Curabitur class aliquam vestibulum nam curae maecenas sed, 
    "Latitude": 28.4195,
    "Longitude": -81.5812
  },
```

but I can't work out how to access this from the map control, I have setup a get and set method in the item's class but don't know how to get the value to load into the Geo co-ordinates.

```
<Maps:MapControl Name="map" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,212.833,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="221" Width="357" ManipulationMode="All" MapServiceToken="AlM1jaSStpZ8pXuB1WYsLCxv1b-KmsrF4IeoZFpsFO9YPQn4xBsA7Os7CkTmNQ02" ZoomLevel="18"/>

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       map.Center = new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geopoint(new    Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition {Longitude = 0 , Latitude = 0 });
       map.ZoomLevel = 18;
       map.Style = Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapStyle.Aerial;
       map.LandmarksVisible = true;
    }
```

any help would be appriecated as I have never done windows app dev before

---

below is updated method that puts a pin down but doesnt direct to the correct co-ordinates

```
private async void addMap(double latitude, double longitude, string title)
    {

        MapIcon MapIcon1 = new MapIcon();
        MapIcon1.Location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition() { Longitude = longitude, Latitude = latitude });
        MapIcon1.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(1.0, 1.0);
        MapIcon1.Title = title;
        LocalMap.MapElements.Add(MapIcon1);

        Geolocator gl = new Geolocator()
        {
            DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High
        };


        try
        {
            Geoposition gp = await gl.GetGeopositionAsync();
            TripDistance.Text = "Long = " + gp.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude + " " + "Lat" + gp.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude;
            //centerMap(gp.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude, gp.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TripDistance.Text = "Error!!";
        }

        LocalMap.Center = new Geopoint (new BasicGeoposition { Latitude = latitude, Longitude = longitude });


        LocalMap.ZoomLevel = 15;
        LocalMap.Style = MapStyle.AerialWithRoads;
        slider.Value = LocalMap.ZoomLevel;
    }
```

Comment: So if I understand you correct you have a json file full of items that contain GeoCoordinates and you want to display markers on the map?

Comment: that is correct, at the minute it is getting the wrong coordinates and putting me in the indian ocean. Please see above for updated method that doesn't go to the correct place